# Save multiple values to same type in LocalStorage then retrieve the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

My main requirement is to generate a URL by clicking on the relevant button. For example
If I click on the green and red button then it should append &_colour=green%2Cred in the url and similar for Gender's button after saving and getting values from localStorage.

example.com/product-category/glasses/**?_gender=women%2Cmen&_colour=green%2Cred**

```
<div class="main-section">
    <div class="section">
        <button data-gender="men">Men</button>
        <button data-gender="women">Women</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <button data-colour="green">green</button>
        <button data-colour="red">Red</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
jQuery('.section button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var gender = jQuery(this).data("gender");
    var colour = jQuery(this).data("colour");
    localStorage.setItem("gender", gender);
    var x = localStorage.getItem("gender");
    console.log(x);
});
```

The question is how to save multiple values against the same type and retrieve the values to create the url.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve multiple values you need to loop through all the buttons in the page and find the ones which have been clicked on. You can toggle a class on the buttons when they are clicked in order to identify them more easily.

From there you can use a loop to build an object from the selected values, adding a new `data-category` attribute to the `.section` elements to provide the keys in that object.

Finally you can use a `URLSearchParams` object to build the updated querystring from that object before applying that to `history.pushState()` to update the current URL.

Put all that together and you get this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-section">
  <div class="section" data-category="gender">
    <button data-value="men">Men</button>
    <button data-value="women">Women</button>
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-category="colour">
    <button data-value="green">green</button>
    <button data-value="red">Red</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $buttons = $('.section button').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).toggleClass('active');
    let data = buildButtonDataObject();
    let querystring = new URLSearchParams(data).toString();

    localStorage.setItem('data', data);
    console.log(data);
    history.pushState(data, 'Page title here', querystring);
    console.log(querystring);
  });
});

let buildButtonDataObject = () => {
  let obj = {};
  $('.section:has(.active)').each((_, s) => obj[s.dataset.category] = $(s).find('button.active').map((_, b) => b.dataset.value).get());
  return obj;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ozc9ms5k/)

In the jsFiddle example, you can see the querystring being updated as you click the buttons by opening the 'Network' panel in dev tools.

Comment: It's great. But can we just console the output of URL instead of history.pushState?

Comment: Of course, just comment the pushState line out and add the `console.log(querystring)` where you need it

Comment: I think there is a small correction 
localStorage.setItem('data', querystring);
we need to pass querystring instead of data.
Am I right?

Comment: You can do either. I'd suggest using the raw `data` object, that way you can work with it directly where necessary instead of being limited by the string.

Comment: Thanks :)
One last question. Is this possible to show only relevant attributes on click. Like if I click on colour button then it only show the color. Right now it shows both attributes like "gender=&amp;colour=red"

Comment: Sure, just use `:has()` in the selector in the `buildButtonDataObject()` function which ensures that there are some `.active` buttons in the current section before adding the property to the object. I updated the answer to show you how

Answer (score 0):

You want to make 1 click function and apply for all button in that and assign to local storage ?

```
  $('.section button').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.on("click", function () {
      var gender = $this.data("gender");
      var colour = $this.data("colour");
      if (gender != undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem("gender", gender);
      }
      if (colour != undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem("colour", colour);
      }
    });
  });
```

I add click function to all element in that class ".section button" and check the data and assign in local storage .

> Easy way just make onclick to button and pass parameter to function and assign it into localstorage.

hope this can help u.

sorry for bad English.